# TFS Test and Build report back as Failed despite 100% tests passed

Tags: tfs, mstest

From my on-premises TFS 2018 I get the following report back:

[image]

How can a test be failed an yet 100% passed?

If I look at the detailed error message it tell me that all steps except for 64 bit tests was successful.

[image]

I'm at a bit of a loss how to troubleshoot here - Only error I have in the log is this error:

> 2017-12-14T03:52:18.5302240Z ##[error]An exception occurred while
>   invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Error while unloading
>   appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)

Comment: Do you use TFS 2018 RTM version? I've tested a simple project with two VSTest tasks, but couldn't reproduce your issue. Could you share the steps to reproduce your scenario?

Comment: By the way, how many tests in your "32 bit tests" task, and how many in "64 bit tests" task?

Comment: It is TFS2018 RTM... It have worked without issue on that version until a few days ago.

Comment: There are only 10 test. They are a bit long (~5 min to run the 10 tests)

Comment: Do you change something in your code recently? Are you able to create another test project to see whether you can reproduce this issue? Also, could you share the steps to reproduce your scenario?

Comment: No, nothing changed in code. Only change was a new VS version on the machine so must be some sort of bug there is my best guess

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? I tested with VS 2017 and the behavior seemed correct. Could you share the entire log?

Comment: It is VIsual Studio 2017

Comment: Are you able to share the entire log?

Comment: The entire log can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnkbjrlfc9x1t9x/64bit%20test%20log.txt?dl=0 + trx file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/54n5q64ftevod2h/MLP-THINK%24_MLP-THINK_2017-12-21_06_03_34.trx?dl=0

Comment: It is build agent 2.122.1... this is the agent the TFS Website link to in the agent pool so would assume it fit the product. (I’ve tried now to upgrade to latest stable release 2.126.0 but that just made it even worse (the agent could not even detect msbuild or VS resulting in nothing working... so back on 2.122.1 now)

Comment: Could you go to build agent machine, find the build working folder, and build the project in the working folder manually to see what result will you get?

Comment: I get same error from VS MS Tests (and Resharper Test runner): https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5bz17kgxto1gh3/UnitTestsNotWorking.png?dl=0

Comment: Since you got the same error from VS, your issue is not due to TFS. Did this issue only happen in VS 2017?

Comment: What do you mean? It also happen via TFS Test And release (aka build agent). And it began happening roughly a month ago (after the test had worked for months properly in VS2017... so it must be a bug in VS/MS build that was introduced in a patch

Comment: TFS calls VS to run the tests, if the issue only happens in TFS, then it is due to TFS. But since you got the same error from VS locally, then this issue is more like from VS or your project side. Could you provide the edition of your VS 2017? And could you provide a test project or detailed steps that could reproduce your issue? I'd like to have a test on my side.

Comment: Visual Studio version is 15.5.2 (Latest as of this writing).Test-project and detailed steps to reproduce is very tricky as the test involve a SAP ERP system being installed + Lucene integration into it so I can't see how a sample project would be possible :-/

Comment: If you create a simple test project, are you able to reproduce this issue? You may check this site (https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/177) to see whether it helps you.